# After moving to Spring 4 my Autowiring breaks

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

I have recently started migrating to Spring 4.1.2 from Spring 3.2.3 and for some reason I keep getting this dependency issue with Autowiring:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.List); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: nz.co.doltech.actions.server.controllers.interceptors.LoggedInInterceptor nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule.loggedInInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.framework.mapping.EntityMapperFactory nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.mapperFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4971)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1487)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:97)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1328)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1420)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:848)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:322)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:556)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:811)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:670)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.List); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: nz.co.doltech.actions.server.controllers.interceptors.LoggedInInterceptor nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule.loggedInInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.framework.mapping.EntityMapperFactory nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.mapperFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: nz.co.doltech.actions.server.controllers.interceptors.LoggedInInterceptor nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule.loggedInInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.framework.mapping.EntityMapperFactory nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.mapperFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1003)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:600)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: nz.co.doltech.actions.server.controllers.interceptors.LoggedInInterceptor nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule.loggedInInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.framework.mapping.EntityMapperFactory nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.mapperFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.framework.mapping.EntityMapperFactory nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.mapperFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.framework.mapping.EntityMapperFactory nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.mapperFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperContext': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.EventService nz.co.doltech.actions.server.mapping.EntityMapperContext.eventService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:949)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:527)
    ... 101 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate nz.co.doltech.actions.server.services.impl.EventServiceImpl.transactionTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.springframework.core.SimpleAliasRegistry.canonicalName(SimpleAliasRegistry.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.isDependent(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:446)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.isDependent(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.isDependent(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.isDependent(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:455)
.. snipped ..
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error, since this worked perfectly fine in Spring 3.2.3. My suspicions were that Spring 4 doesn't lazy load the dependencies by default so I added initLazy = true to all my @ComponentScan references. I see that the issue is a "cyclic" dependency but its one that shouldn't be causing a StackOverflowException, especially if it was working fine in an older version. Have I missed a configuration setting or perhaps something that needs to be altered in Spring 4?

Here is my applications relevant setup classes: https://gist.github.com/BenDol/080169ee25e8d4f231f4

Comment: Post your application context

Comment: I don't use an XML application context, it is done with @Configuration it is a large application split up into multiple modules the gist I posted gives the relevant context configurations. Is there anything specific you need to see? Here is the entry point code: https://gist.github.com/BenDol/d3a73e9d9cb16325b2f5

Comment: `'nz.co.doltech.actions.server.spring.BaseMvcModule': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not` Looks like you have a couple of custom beans that you haven't wired up

Comment: The StackOverflowError is the real problem I believe, when ever it tries to autowire the TransactionTemplate dependency this is thrown. I made this lazy load and the error goes away until I invoke the SettingsServiceImpl which auto wires the TransactionTemplate. Really strange.

Comment: Here is the result of debugging the stack overflow error: https://gist.github.com/BenDol/adbcfce667ed826445c7

Comment: Why is TransactionTemplate a prototype?

Comment: Because I want a new instance of the TranasctionTemplate every time its called rather than the default Singleton scope.

Comment: When I remove prototype scope it starts working... do you know why this is? An explanation on why this is the case would be awesome :D Ill mark that the answer to this thread :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why would you need a new instance of the template? It is thread safe and having multiple copies doesn't really make sense... Especially if you use prototype it will each time be configured the same. Just use a single instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The prototype scope will create a new object every time it is injected. A singleton will only instantiate 1 instance and use that instance every time it is injected.

So everytime that TransactionTemplate bean is requested, a new one is created.

Your EventService and EmailService have a cyclic dependency and depends on TransactionTemplate. You pretty much answered all of your questions in your comments.

1. Cyclic Dependency
2. Prototype pattern on dependency on each item.

The result is an infinite TransactionTemplate creation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use all the spring jars related to Spring 4.1.2. completely remove spring 3.x jars.